# Weird Ad site has appeared on my domain while name server is being transferred. Is this normal?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, host

This morning, I tried switching the name servers to one of my godaddy domain names over to hostgator name servers. I was told it can take up to 48 hours for this switch to be made.

I just checked the domain and it routed to the following website. Is this normal during a name server change?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a "parked" landing page. It's something that website hosts do when you are pointing a domain name to them that they don't recognise yet, or that some DNS registrars do when you have not configured your domain with them, but are pointing to their nameservers.

Comment: so during DNS propagation, it is normal?

Comment: No, it is not normal. Is the domain properly configured at Hostgator's side? As Mark mentioned above, looks like Hostgator does not recognise your domain.

Comment: I haven't necessarily done anything on hostgator's side. I've only configured the name servers on godaddy's side.

Comment: @Byron usually when you transfer your DNS, you set up your new DNS before changing your nameservers over. Then you don't get these pages. So yes, it's "normal" if you have not configured your DNS, but it's not "normal" during a DNS migration because you should have configured your new DNS before switching.